# Python Robot Framework : How to convert robot's txt code into Python code

Tags: robotframework, robots.txt

Please tell me how to convert following robot (txt) code into Python code. Robot code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem
*** Keywords ***
nik_key_1
    [Arguments]           ${arg1_str}
    log to console      ${arg1_str}
*** Variables ***
${var1}         "variable1"
*** Test Cases ***
First Test Case
    ${output}=   run     "hostname"
    log to console      ${output}
    ${str1}=    catenate    "nikhil"    "gupta"
    nik_key_1               "NikArg1"
    log to console      ${var1}
    log to console      ${str1}
```

Following is the code that I tried :

```
from robot.api import TestSuite
from robot.running.model import Keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.api.deco import keyword
bi = BuiltIn()

@keyword(name='nik_key_1')
def nik_key_1(username):
    bi.log_to_console(message=username,stream='STDOUT',no_newline=False)

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
suite.resource.imports.library("OperatingSystem")
keyword1 = Keyword(name="nik_key_1",type='kw',doc="nik_key_doc1",args=
["nikusername"])
suite.keywords.append(keyword1)
test = suite.tests.create(name='nik_test_case1', tags=['smoke'])
test.doc = "nik doc"
print dir(test.keywords)
test.keywords.create('nik_key_1', args=['nikusername'],type='kw')

result = suite.run(critical='smoke', output='skynet.xml')
```

Following is the error I am getting :

```
No keyword with name 'nik_key_1' found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because robot doesn't look at your script for context, and thus doesn't know about the `nik_key_1`. Since your suite doesn't import this script, it can't access any functions. You'll need to move `nik_key_1` to a file, and import that file in the suite.

For example, create a file named `keywords.py`, and put this in it:

```
# keywords.py
from robot.api.deco import keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

bi = BuiltIn()

@keyword(name='nik_key_1')
def nik_key_1(username):
    bi.log_to_console(message=username,stream='STDOUT',no_newline=False)
```

Next, modify your test to include this library:

```
suite.resource.imports.library('keywords.py')
```

You can then call the keyword from your test.

### Using your script as a library

It's possible to combine your script and the keywords in a single file, but that involves making your script importable by protecting the executable code from running when the file is imported.

For example, you can rewrite your script to be like the following. Notice how the executable portion of the script is inside a block that tests whether the file is imported or not. Also notice that the script itself is added as a library (`suite.resource.imports.library(__file__)`)

```
from robot.api import TestSuite
from robot.running.model import Keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.api.deco import keyword

bi = BuiltIn()

@keyword(name='nik_key_1')
def nik_key_1(username):
    bi.log_to_console(message=username,stream='STDOUT',no_newline=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
   suite.resource.imports.library('OperatingSystem')
   suite.resource.imports.library(__file__)
   test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])
   test.keywords.create('Set Environment Variable', args=['SKYNET', 'activated'], type='setup')
   test.keywords.create('Environment Variable Should Be Set', args=['SKYNET'])
   test.keywords.create('nik_key_1', args=['nikusername'],type='kw')
   result = suite.run(critical='smoke', output='skynet.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bryan. I am new to Robot Framework. Will keep posting more questions related to Robot. Thanks.